# Why is String.equals("word") not working for me?

Tags: java, string

The normal code works below

```
ShipSize size = shipSize.startsWith("s") ? ShipSize.SMALL: 
    (shipSize.startsWith("m") ? ShipSize.MEDIUM: ShipSize.LARGE); // get ship size
```

Is this the right way to change the code so the string equals a word. I doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
ShipSize size = shipSize.equals("small") ? ShipSize.SMALL: 
    (shipSize.equals("medium") ? ShipSize.MEDIUM: ShipSize.LARGE); // get ship size
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Use a `switch`. Better yet, use the `enum` as its intended.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't seem to work?

Comment: See my answer but it's unclear here what your input is. My answer assumes that the input string is, case insensitive-wise, the same as the enum constant

Comment: `equals` is case-sensitive. is the `shipSize` String always going to be lowercase? If not, there's also `equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: Additional, make sure that shipSize isn't pointing to a different memory slot, so it mostly produces false for equals.

Comment: @00Enthusiast equals checks the values, not the memory location.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this assumes that your inputs are actually `"small"`, `"medium"` or `"large"` and that your enum is:

```
public enum ShipSize
{
    SMALL,
    MEDIUM,
    LARGE,
    ;
}
```

If this is the case, you can just do:

```
final ShipSize size = ShipSize.valueOf(shipSize.toUpperCase());
```

`.valueOf()` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the constant does not exist, so if the risk exists you should catch that and recover appropriately.

Comment: @zubergu I suggest you read the question again... Do you actually believe that "supersized" will result in `ShipSize.SMALL`?

Comment: @zubergu this does not prevent one from trying and guessing what the user really wants; experience, as you put it, is a double edged sword. You end up intuitively understanding what the problem is about, and your "nitpickiness" prompts you to query for more details in comments instead where a straight answer might just be what the OP is asking for. Ohwell...

Comment: @zubergu and I should edit what, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Equals is case sensitive, depending on your input, so you may need to use `.equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `.equals()`

Other than that, you haven't done anything "wrong". You'll need to specify exactly what your input is for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
ShipSize size = "small".equalsIgnoreCase(shipSize.name) ? ShipSize.SMALL: ("medium".equalsIgnoreCase(shipSize.name) ? ShipSize.MEDIUM: ShipSize.LARGE); // get ship size
```

Assuming ShipSize is an enum, then you can use the .name of the enum to get the String.  Also, put the constants first when comparing to avoid possible null pointer exceptions.

EDIT:  changed to equalsIgnoreCase.